# Object cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest with Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-webflow, classcastexception

I'm trying to integrate Spring MVC with Spring WebFlow. In order to share session data between both of them I came up with this solution that actually works fine:

```
public String prepareForPayment(RequestContext context, Authentication currentUser) {
    PaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails();

    // CODE HERE

    HttpServletRequest request =       (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("paymentDetails", paymentDetails);

    // CODE HERE

}
```

Then in a Controller **outside** webflow I can easily get session data:

```
PaymentDetails paymentDetails = (PaymentDetails)session.getAttribute("paymentDetails");
```

So above code works fine and I'm able to set and get session attributes.

Now, when I write a test for this class I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Why my test is throwing `ClassCastException` and how to solve it?

Comment: sounds like you are using mocking during test and not actual context, maybe that's why it cant cast back?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my code again and I think the whole *"problem"* came from me trying to return `Object` instead of `HttpServletRequest` directly. Therefore, I caused `ClassCastException`. This piece of code works fine:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
    @Mock
    private RequestContext           context;

    @Mock
    private ExternalContext          externalContext;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest       httpServletRequest;

    @Mock
    private HttpSession              httpSession;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Mockito.when(context.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
        Mockito.when(externalContext.getNativeRequest()).thenReturn(httpServletRequest);
        Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(httpSession);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `HttpServletRequest` from `RequestContext` by calling `getRequest()` method.

[Refer this Spring RequestContext Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContext.html#getRequest--)

Comment: The problem is that my RequestContext is org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext and not org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext

Comment: @iaforek be specific..!!
Try to debug code u will get solution.

Comment: I'm specific. Key word here is: Spring Webflow. Without it everything is easy and straight-forward. I tried to debug it and looked for an answer in the Internet. Because, I can't find anything I've decided to post a question here. Hoping that someone will be able to help me.

Comment: @iaforek i never work on webflow..
Hope u will get answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I rewritten some of the code and in the end I used:

```
PaymentDetails paymentDetails = (PaymentDetails) context.getConversationScope().get("paymentDetails");
```

and in my test:

```
@Mock
private RequestContext context;

@Mock
private MutableAttributeMap attMap;

private PaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails();

// CODE HERE

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Use paymentDetails methods and set values. For example:
    paymentDetails.setCurrency("GBP");

    // CODE HERE

    Mockito.when(context.getConversationScope()).thenReturn(attMap);
    Mockito.when(attMap.get("paymentDetails")).thenReturn(paymentDetails);
    // CODE HERE
}
```